# Скрипт меняющейся строки

Tags: javascript

На сайте http://www.bfm.ru/ вверху страницы есть надпись "В фокусе". напротив этой надписи появляются (меняются) ссылки. Подскажите, где можно найти аналогичный скрипт. Я право даже не знаю, как его назвать. Сам написать не смогу. Нужен исходник. Заранее огромное спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Это карусель. [Тысячи их](https://www.google.ru/search?q=jquery+carousel). Самое простое решение - взять код с сайта, который вы указали.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.htmldrive.net/items/show/411/Super-simple-jQuery-ticker-text-slideshow